# Barcode detection using zbar python not working for all documents

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am trying to recognise/detect the barcode from the following document using [zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar). Here is the code that I have used from a [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-using-zbar-and-opencv/) to test out the library on the data that I have.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import argparse

def decode(im):
    # Find barcodes and QR codes
    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im)

    # Print results
    for obj in decodedObjects:
        print('Type : ', obj.type)
        print('Data : ', obj.data, '\n')

    return decodedObjects  # Display barcode and QR code location


def display(im, decodedObjects):
    # Loop over all decoded objects
    for decodedObject in decodedObjects:
        points = decodedObject.polygon

    # If the points do not form a quad, find convex hull
    if len(points) > 4:
        hull = cv2.convexHull(np.array([point for point in points], dtype=np.float32))
        hull = list(map(tuple, np.squeeze(hull)))
    else:
        hull = points


    # Number of points in the convex hull
    n = len(hull)

    # Draw the convext hull
    for j in range(0, n):
        cv2.line(im, hull[j], hull[(j + 1) % n], (0, 255, 0), 50)  # Display results
        cv2.imshow("Results", imutils.resize(im, 500))
        cv2.waitKey(0)  # Main


def display_ppn(im, decoded_objects, draw='rect'):
    if draw == 'rect':
        all_barcodes = []
        for decoded_object in decoded_objects:
            points = [[x, y] for x, y in (decoded_object.polygon)]
            all_barcodes.append(points)
        print(all_barcodes)

    else:
        all_barcodes = []
        for decoded_object in decoded_objects:
            points = [[x, y] for x, y in (decoded_object.polygon)]
            all_barcodes.append(points)
        print(all_barcodes)
        for barcode in all_barcodes:
            cv2.polylines(im, [np.array(barcode)], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Results", imutils.resize(im, 500))
        cv2.waitKey(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creates parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # parser arguments:
    parser.add_argument('image', type=str, help='Path to image of form')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread(args.image)

    decodedObjects = decode(im)
    display_ppn(im, decodedObjects)
```

While some of the documents are working fine, the majority of them are not. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can get a 100% **detection**? Will increasing the barcode size or type help? The input images that I have will always be binarised.

**Working Samples**

[image: Working Document 1]
[image: Working Document 2]

**Failed Samples**

[image: Failed Document 1]
[image: Failed Document 2]

Comment: If you want to look at a picture, you always have to look at the right angle. Otherwise, you lose the size of the depth. Sharpness is very important in color separation.

Comment: @dsgdfg Are you suggesting I rotate the image so that the bar code is straight?

Answer (score 0):

Straightening may help the recognition software find the barcodes, but because of aliasing, many of these codes have bars and spaces narrowed or thickened. I would not expect 100% success reading every code. I suggest you isolate the barcode sticker with software using the whitespace around the barcode and perform OCR on the characters present underneath.